# Canonical identification of $T_p M$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The following exercise is taken from M. do Carmo's *Riemannian Geometry* book

[image: Exercise]

The problem is that I can't interpret it. In order that $P$ becomes an isometry, it should be a differentiable map between Riemannian manifolds. Despite $T_{c(t_0)} M$ and $T_{c(t)} M$ being isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$ (which is Riemannian manifold with Euclidean metric), there is no canonical identification I can find in the literature.

Comment: You don't need an identification. You can work abstractly with the mapping between inner product spaces to check that a map is a linear map and an isometry.

Comment: I think in this context you can take isometry to mean "inner product preserving linear bijection between vector spaces" instead of "metric tensor preserving diffeomorphism between manifolds".

Comment: @TedShifrin I believe that by definition of isometry, I need to show that $\langle P_* v, P_* w \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle$ where $v, w \in T_X(T_{c(t_0)} M)$ i.e. the tangent space of the tangent space $T_{c(t_0)} M$ at the point $X \in T_{c(t_0)} M$ and $P_*$ is pushforward.

Comment: @ziggurism Did you mean something like $\langle v, w \rangle_{c(t_0)} = \langle P(v), P(w) \rangle_{c(t)}$ for all $v, w \in T_{c(t_0)} M$?